# BigCommerce -- Assign global variable as javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

Is it possible to assign a BigCommerce global variable to a javascript var in order to modify the text appropriately? For example:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var test = %%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%;

    //insert modification to "test" here

    $(document).ready(function()  {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = test;
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

EDIT:

I tried doing:

```
var test = '%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%'
```

This works fine for some descriptions but not all. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: what does this output in html ?

Comment: It doesn't output anything in the HTML. I'm thinking there might be a special way to assign that global variable to a Javascript var... but I don't know what.

Comment: We're talking about the HTML source code. You need to "view source" and look at what is being output by your server. Chances are some of your products contain a `'` which is causing a syntax error.

Comment: I checked that earlier and noticed that it has some specific formatting for most descriptions. Do you know if there's a way to make this work without having to change the formatting of the description itself? Or will that have to get edited?

Comment: (1) You don't need the CDATA. (2) I hope you are not really trying to put an HTML comment inside a script.

Comment: No, lol. It's not there in the code itself, don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you may have had issues when attempting to assign the variable is if your product description has single quotes in inside of it.

My recommendation would be to set the variable equal to the container element of the description.

```
<div id="ProductDescription">
    %%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%
</div>
```

Then the JS

```
var productDesc = $('#ProductDescription').html();
```

or if you just want plain text

```
var productDesc = $('#ProductDescription').text();
```

Comment: No problem. Best of luck with the rest of your build, I'll see you around!